# Generating PDF file with types (not format) per page

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am working on a software producing multi-pages PDF documents - to be printed in local offices.
Pages have different sizes, but mostly different types.

For instance (here is just 2, there is actually much more) :

A4 with simple informations, that should be printed on cheap paper
A4 expected to be signed and archived, with specific paper

I'd like to embed a "page type" with each page, that can be mapped on a config in the machine to an actual printing profil (selecting the right tray and printing parameters).

What is the best field to store the page type ?
Do you know of a Java lib that can handle that properly ?
Do you have other suggestion to handle this ?

I was able to have it working for different page format (A4, A5, Letter...) in the same document.
So far I did not find a good way to handle different printing profil, defined at document generation, that can be used by the printer.

Thanks !

Comment: 1) what do you mean with "page type" ? 2) if I got it rigth, you have a single PDF that contains multiple pages, and different pages has to be printed in diffferent way, but in the same document. I'm rigth ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Stefano Riffaldi Yes that is correct. The idea is to have some form of metadata per page, that can be mapped to a printing profile (trail, quality, color, etc...)

Comment: @K J - Currently we are printing directly from the application, using iText. It's getting more and more complex to manage the printers configs etc..
Hence the project to now rely on pdf generation with metadata, removing the responsibility to interact with the printers from the server.

Comment: If you are using iText at the server, you can easily add any kind of additional information into each PDF page object. Then you would need to read that information out by a custom software that does the printing.

Comment: sometime to carry some 'metadata' in pages we used annotations. write customs XMP is a bit complicated for our purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was nice and make me interested. It's quite a nice exercise. As I said in the comment, it's basically about carrying sort of metadata for each page. I think that the best practice is to use XMP, but it's quite a bit complicated, and in all scenario I had to worked with that, I gives up. To make an approach simple and efficient, we can use annotations to carry those data.

That's a full sample, ofc I've mocked printer ;).

```
package org.example;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfStampAnnotation;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.experimental.StandardException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Question: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/77981954/11289119">Generating PDF file with types (not format) per page</a>
 *
 * @author stefano-riffaldi
 */
@Slf4j
public class ProfilePrinting {

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create sample empty PDF document with 5 pages
        Path sourcePdfPath = Files.createTempFile("tmp-source-", ".pdf");
        try (
                OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(sourcePdfPath);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputStream))
        ) {
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
        }
        // set profile metadata to PDF document
        Path profiledPdfPath = Files.createTempFile("tmp-dest-", ".pdf");
        log.info("Source file: {}", profiledPdfPath);
        log.info("Dest   file: {}", profiledPdfPath);
        try (
                InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(sourcePdfPath);
                OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(profiledPdfPath);
                Profiler profiler = new ITextProfiler(inputStream, outputStream)
        ) {
            profiler.setProfiles(Arrays.asList(Profile.A, Profile.B, Profile.B, Profile.B, null, Profile.C));
        }
        // printPage PDF document with profiles
        try (
                InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(profiledPdfPath);
                Printer printer = new ITextProfiledPrinter(inputStream)
        ) {
            printer.printAll();
        }
    }

    public enum Profile {
        A, B, C, D, DEFAULT
    }

    public interface Printer extends AutoCloseable {

        void printAll();

        void printPage(int page);

        void printRange(int fromInclusive, int toInclusive);
    }

    public interface Profiler extends AutoCloseable {

        List<Profile> getProfiles();

        void setProfiles(List<Profile> profiles);
    }

    public static class ITextProfiledPrinter implements Printer {
        private final PdfDocument pdfDocument;
        private final List<Profile> profiles;

        public ITextProfiledPrinter(InputStream is) {
            try {
                pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(is));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new PdfException(e);
            }
            profiles = new ITextProfiler(pdfDocument).getProfiles();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            pdfDocument.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void printAll() {
            printRange(1, pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages());
        }

        @Override
        public void printPage(int page) {
            printRange(page, page);
        }

        @Override
        public void printRange(int fromInclusive, int toInclusive) {
            for (int page = fromInclusive; page <= toInclusive; page++) {
                log.debug("Printing page {} with profile '{}'", page, profiles.get(page - 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ITextProfiler implements Profiler {
        private static final String PREFIX = "PrintProfile_";
        private final PdfDocument pdfDocument;

        private ITextProfiler(PdfDocument pdfDocument) { // scope: package-private
            this.pdfDocument = pdfDocument;
        }

        public ITextProfiler(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
            try {
                pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(is), new PdfWriter(os));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new PdfException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            log.debug("Closing and saving document");
            pdfDocument.close();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
            List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                List<PdfAnnotation> annotations = pdfDocument.getPage(i + 1).getAnnotations();
                log.debug("Page {}, annotations: {}", i + 1, annotations.size());
                Profile profile = annotations.stream()
                        .map(this::getProfile).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .findFirst().orElse(null);
                profiles.add(profile);
            }
            return profiles;
        }

        @Override
        public void setProfiles(List<Profile> profiles) {
            for (int i = 0; i < profiles.size(); i++) {
                Profile profile = profiles.get(i);
                log.debug("Adding annotation to page {} with profile '{}'", i + 1, profile);
                addAnnotation(pdfDocument.getPage(i + 1), profile);
            }
        }

        private void addAnnotation(PdfPage page, Profile profile) {
            if (profile == null) {
                return;
            }
            // customize type of annotation to choose proper type, appearance, etc
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
            PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect)
                    .setName(new PdfString(PREFIX + profile.name()))
                    .setFlags(PdfAnnotation.HIDDEN);
            // PDF Reference 1.4: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.4.pdf
            // 8.4.2 Annotation Flags
            // Hidden (PDF 1.2): If set, do not display or print the annotation or allow it to interact
            // with the user, regardless of its annotation type or whether an annotation
            // handler is available. In cases where screen space is limited, the ability to hide
            // and show annotations selectively can be used in combination with appearance
            // streams (see Section 8.4.4, “Appearance Streams”) to display auxiliary pop-up
            // information similar in function to online help systems. (See implementation
            // note 63 in Appendix H.)
            page.addAnnotation(annotation);
            log.debug("Added annotation to page {} with profile '{}'", page.getDocument().getPageNumber(page), profile);
        }

        private Profile getProfile(PdfAnnotation annotation) {
            // customize behavior to get the profile, if the annotation contains that information
            String titleString = annotation.getName().toString();
            try {
                if (titleString.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
                    return Profile.valueOf(titleString.substring(PREFIX.length()));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // do nothing, just return null
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @StandardException
    private static class PdfException extends RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! With this we could at least decorrelate the generation and the printing, using a custom printing module.
I will try to delegate the whole printing logic (ITextProfiledPrinter) to the printer configuration in Windows, I have now only little hope that it can be done :)

Comment: yrw, I'm sure that it's not the best practice to achieve that goal (carry metadata in pages), it's a sneaky trick but works, so ..